# jquery flip! component: highchart is no longer interactive?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts, flip

I have a page containing a table and an highchart that displays some values. Using the Flip! component i'm trying to switch between the two objects but when i do so, highchart lose all it's interactivity (the tooltip is no longer displayed, the zoom option doesn't work and so on).
has anybody already faced this problem and know how to solve it?

Here some html:

this is a button

```
<span id="button"> button </span>
```

this is the flip:

```
<div id="flip">here is my flip container</div>
```

this is the div containing the object

```
<div style="display: none">
   <table id="table"> some values </table>
   <div id="chart">Highchart</div>
</div>
```

here is how i switch:

```
$('#button').button().click(function(){
    $('#flip').flip({
        direction: 'bt',
        content:$('#chart'),
        color: 'white',
        speed: 200
        });
});
```

Comment: It is possible to recreate yoru example in the jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle example ---> [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/tVhTL/) hope you could give me a hint :D
PS: remove the display: none from the <div> to see highchart working

Comment: Please take look at http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab which is related with your issue, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the chart is drawn while the container is not visible. Try drawing the chart after the container is visible. Put the Highchart in a function, and call that on the flip transition, or predefine the highchart variable and just run the highcharts jQuery code right after the flip command (maybe with a callback?)

I'm not sure about this flip plugin, but maybe something like the code below would do the trick...

```
$('#button').button().click(function(){
  $('#flip').flip({
    direction: 'bt',
    content:$('#chart'),
    color: 'white',
    speed: 200
  }).each( function() { drawChart(); });
});

function drawChart() {
// draw the chart here
}
```